# Can't install mysql gem on OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Server

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, osx-server, ruby-on-rails-4

Having trouble installing mysql ruby gem on OS X Server 10.6.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
macserver:~ admin$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-       config=/usr/bin/mysql_config

Building native extensions. This could take a while…

ERROR: Error installing mysql:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config

checking for mysql_ssl_set()… yes
checking for rb_str_set_len()… yes
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()… yes
checking for mysql.h… no
checking for mysql/mysql.h… no

*** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-config

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the development headers for MySQL installed. The default binary package from Oracle does not include these.

If you're using either Homebrew or MacPorts, both of these will be able to provide the required files.